# How to add confidence intervals for a line chart in (React) ApexCharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, confidence-interval, apexcharts

Using ApexCharts (more specifically, React-ApexCharts), how can I create a mean line plus a shaded region that visually shows the uncertainty of the estimate (e.g. quantiles, confidence intervals)?

The target output is similar to:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, ApexCharts doesn't offer this functionality out of the box. The following is a workaround inspired by [this answer on GitHub from Phili230](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/1980#issuecomment-818590841).

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
const data = {
  labels: [
    "2022-01-01",
    "2022-02-01",
    "2022-03-01",
    "2022-04-01",
    "2022-05-01",
    "2022-06-01"
  ],
  mean: [14, 16, 18, 15, 19, 16],
  low: [11.5, 14, 15, 12.5, 17, 14.5],
  high: [15.6, 18, 20.5, 16.5, 21, 17]
};
export default function App() {
  const series = [
    {
      name: "95th quantile",
      type: "area",
      data: data.high
    },
    {
      name: "5th quantile",
      type: "area",
      data: data.low
    },
    {
      name: "mean",
      type: "line",
      data: data.mean
    }
  ];
  const options = {
    chart: {
      stacked: false
    },
    title: { text: "Mean estimate by month" },
    labels: data.labels,
    fill: {
      colors: ["#94ddf7", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF"],
      opacity: [0.5, 1.0, 1.0],
      type: "solid"
    },
    stroke: {
      show: true,
      colors: ["#94ddf7", "#94ddf7", "#0674fe"],
      width: [2, 2, 5]
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: "datetime"
    },
    grid: {
      strokeDashArray: 0,
      position: "front"
    },
    legend: { show: false },
    tooltip: { inverseOrder: true },
    yaxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: "Mean estimate"
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Chart
      options={options}
      series={series}
      type="line"
      width={"100%"}
      height={"500px"}
    />
  );
}
```

#### CodeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-benji-w34gz3

#### Remarks

- The order in which the series are defined is important, as the background brought by the "low" bar must on top of that brought by the "high" bar
- The grid also has to be brought to the front
- An undesired side-effect is that the grid is above the mean, low and high lines